# setInterval after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var playtop = setInterval(goright, 5000);

function goright(){
...
}
```

The above works.

Now, I need to interrupt the above by clicking on a button, do something on page, and ten seconds after click - activate the `setInterval` again.

```
$("#btngoright").click(function(){
    clearInterval(playtop);
    ...
    setTimeout(playtop, 10000);
});
```

But, once interrupted, `setInterval` is not activated again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because `playtop` is the id that was returned when initially setting the interval.

The `setTimeout` method expects a function, not an id, therefore you should pass a reference to the `goright` function again:

```
setTimeout(goright, 10000);
```

If you want to activate the interval again *after* 10 seconds, you can set an interval and pass a reference to the `goright` function in an anonymous function:

```
$("#btngoright").click(function(){
    clearInterval(playtop);

    setTimeout(function () {
      setInterval(goright, 5000);
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: but `goright` is a function which is, in this case, executed only once !

Answer (score 1):

Nearly. It should be:

```
$("#btngoright").click(function(){
    clearInterval(playtop);

    setTimeout(function () {
      playtop = setInterval(goright, 5000);
    }, 10000);
});
```

This way you are putting control back into the playtop variable meaning that the interrupt function will work more than once.